# Disable Google Transliterate In javascript

Tags: javascript

I had this webpage in which I had integrated Google Transliterate Input Tools.
However, I am unable to disable it.
On their website, it is given how to disable it with `.disableTransliterate()` but I dont know how or where to put it. Please help me, I am a beginner.

https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started#transliterationControl

Comment: This is a deprecated feature. Don't use it

Comment: By deprecated you mean that It's functions don't work anymore ?

Comment: All of Google Transliterate is deprecated. It still works for now, but it may stop working with little notice.

Comment: provide us some code please ...

Comment: Actually that's pretty much all they've provided on their website.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the the function `.disableTransliteration()` on the `control` object that you created at time of initializing the instance.

What you can do is :

```
<script>
   var control;
   function onLoad() {
        var options = {
            sourceLanguage:
                 google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
            destinationLanguage:
                 [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.HINDI],
            shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
            transliterationEnabled: true
        };

        // Create an instance on TransliterationControl with the required
       // options.
       control = new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);

       // Enable transliteration in the textbox with id
       // 'transliterateArea'.
       control.makeTransliteratable(['transliterateArea']);
  }

  //To run the instance
  google.setOnloadCallback(onLoad);

  // To turn off the transliteration
  control.disableTransliteration();

</script>
```

Above script works for me :)